# Efficient way to get data from multiple joins on a table

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am a newbie to writing SQL and  have a legacy system at my hands to work upon with three tables as given below :

```
Table A
=========
id | tracker_id | created_on |      status                    | p_id
1  |      1     |     ...    |  (Table C latest new_val ) 4   |  121

Table B
=========
id | a_id | created_on | 
1  | 1    | 2013-12-12 15:15:16
2  | 1    | 2013-12-15 15:20:16
3  | 1    | 2013-12-15 15:25:16
4  | 1    | 2013-12-15 15:30:16
5  | 1    | 2013-12-15 16:20:16
6  | 1    | 2013-12-16 17:20:16
7  | 1    | 2013-12-25 16:25:16


Table C
=========
id | b_id | type | old_val | new_val
1  | 1    | type1|  1      | 2
2  | 2    | type1|  2      | 3
3  | 3    | type1|  3      | 4
4  | 4    | type1|  4      | 5
5  | 5    | type1|  5      | 3
6  | 6    | type1|  3      | 5
7  | 7    | type1|  5      | 3
```

I want to get the count of Table A ids between any specific dates say 2013-12-13 and 2013-12-17 with the specific latest value of Table C new_val between that time range , so in above case if i query between  "2013-12-13 and 2013-12-17" with p_id as 121 and  Table C new_val as 5 i should get 1 . Also if i query between  "2013-12-13 and 2013-12-17" with Table C new_val as 3 i should get 0 .

I have written a query of form

```
Select count(tableA.id) from tableA tableA 
    inner join tableB tableB on tableA.id=tableB.a_id
    inner join tableC tableCdetails on tableB.id=tableCdetails.b_id
    where tableCdetails.type = 'type1'  and tableCdetails.new_val='5'
    and  tableB.created_on between '2013-12-13' AND '2013-12-17' 
    and tableA.p_id = 121
```

I have tried a few combinations using trial and error method and i am getting certain values with above query for certain cases , however this does not match for some other values in the system . I think i am missing the fact that i need to pick up the latest tableB id for the time range and match the new_val for tableC entry  corresponding to that tableB id , unfortunately i unable to figure out how to get it . Can someone direct me how to get that done in the above query or with any other approach (or i am doing the query in completely wrong way ) .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do need to get the latest b value.  One way is to put the condition in the `from` clause as an additional join.  Another way is to use the `where` clause, with a correlated subquery:

```
where tableB.created_on = (select max(created_on)
                           from tableB b2
                           where b2.a_id = tableA.id
                          ) and
       . . . /* the rest of your conditions here */
```

Comment: Added the following code and it worked  pretty nicely , no issues so far

"where tableB.created_on = (select max(created_on)
                           from tableB b2
                           where b2.a_id = tableA.id and created_on between '2013-12-13' AND '2013-12-17')"